# how to pass object from one activity to another activity in android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I am new to android Kotlin. I am trying to Pass object from one activity to another activity I got stuck,

MyClass :

```
data class MyPojo(val name: String, val age: String) : Serializable
```

FirstActivity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val editTextName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.EditName)
    val editTextAge = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.EditAge)

    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.ButtonSend)

    button.setOnClickListener {

      val object1 = MyPojo(editTextName.text.toString(),editTextAge.text.toString())

        val intent = Intent(this,Main2Activity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Obj",object1)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
  }
}
```

SecondActivity :

```
class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

    val obj :MyPojo = intent.getSerializableExtra("obj") as MyPojo

    val textView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textViewName)
    val textViewAge : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textViewAge)

    textView.setText(obj.name)
    textViewAge.setText(obj.age)

  }
}
```

Error :

> 6-28 19:35:58.625
> 22192-22192/com.example.evalai.passingobjecttoactivity
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.evalai.passingobjecttoactivity, PID: 22192
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.evalai.passingobjecttoactivity/com.example.evalai.passingobjecttoactivity.Main2Activity}:
> kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type
> com.example.evalai.passingobjecttoactivity.MyPojo
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
> Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.example.evalai.passingobjecttoactivity.MyPojo
> at com.example.evalai.passingobjecttoactivity.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.kt:14)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)

Comment: You used `Obj` in one place and `obj` in the other... -_-

Comment: yes...!Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key you are providing for storing your pojo into the Intent is not the same key you are using to read it (you are storing with "Obj" and reading with "obj").

When you read the intent in your Main2Activity, there is nothing stored with that key, so you return null. And, obviously, you can't cast null to MyPojo.

To avoid these problems, you should always declare a constant for the keys of your intents:

```
const val ARG_POJO = "argPojo"
```

And use it to store and read from them:

Store:

```
intent.putExtra(ARG_POJO, object1)
```

Read:

```
val obj: MyPojo = intent.getSerializableExtra(ARG_POJO) as MyPojo
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Make your data class serializable

```
data class MyPojo(val name: String, val age: String) : Serializable
```

Step 2: From Sending Activity

```
val object1 = MyPojo(editTextName.text.toString(),editTextAge.text.toString())
val intent = Intent(this,Main2Activity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("Obj",object1 as Serializable)
startActivity(intent)
```

Step 3: At receiving activity

```
val receivedObject:MyPojo=intent?.getSerializableExtra(Obj) as MyPojo
```

That's it.